# Butcher block support over base cabinets. Is this adequate?

Tags: countertops

I am installing butcher block over these base cabinets in my laundry room. I had to raise the counter top up 3/4” so the counter top clears the drawers.

My question is, are these supports going to be adequate to support my butcher block (after attached)? Or should I also add some braces going the opposite way (from wall to wall)?

Counter top is 39” deep by 62” long and 1.5” thick. It is birch.

[image]

Comment: What is the wood type and the dimensions of the butcher block you want to use?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - 62” x 39” and it’s birch

Comment: How thick is it?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - it is 1.5” thick

Comment: I'd guess it would probably be ok without cross bracing, but would suggest putting your supports directly above cabinet vertical pieces to help hold the weight and not rely on the cabinet trim to hold the weight _especially in front.  That front trim probably isn't very sturdy in supporting weight with the drawers directly underneath the front of the supports.  I'd suggest moving the left and right ones all the way to the edges to carry the load down to the base cabinets on each side, and then put one in the middle-ish area directly above the seam of the two cabinets.

Comment: Agree 100%, @Milwrdfan. Make that an answer and you'll have my +1. After all, in most cases, the counter top would be placed directly on top of the cabinets without any extra blocking at all and nobody worries about that. It would be just fine with exactly 3 supports - at the left wall, at the right wall, and directly down the middle. One full-length across the back (as it is here) is good, too.

Comment: Is it really 1.5" thick all the way back, or does it have a 1.5" thick "overhang" in front (leading to the need for you to raise it to clear the drawers) with the bulk of the material being significantly thinner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying a comment to an answer...

I'd guess it would probably be ok without cross bracing, but would suggest putting your supports directly above cabinet vertical pieces to help hold the weight and not rely on the cabinet trim to hold the weight _especially in front. That front trim probably isn't very sturdy in supporting weight with the drawers directly underneath the front of the supports. I'd suggest moving the left and right ones all the way to the edges to carry the load down to the base cabinets on each side, and then put one in the middle-ish area directly above the seam of the two cabinets.